# 2018: moderação do site em números

Tags: debate, moderação, estatísicas

A lot of thanks to [@hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) for the translation!

---

Gostaria de compartilhar com vocês um relatório sobre a moderação do Stack Overflow em Português.

Uma característica distinta dos sites da rede Stack Exchange é a forma como estes são moderados:

> A rede Stack Exchange foi desenhada para ser auto-regulada, de modo que o custo de moderação do sistema é amortizado em milhares de pequenas porções de esforço diário dos usuários regulares.
>   -- [*A Theory of Moderation*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

Embora existam [Moderadores](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/), uma parte significativa da *moderação* é feita por pessoas comuns, usando os privilégios obtidos através das suas contribuições ao site. Cada um de vocês contribui com um pouco do seu tempo e esforço, e juntos todos conseguem realizar muita coisa.

Ao entrar em um novo ano, vamos fazer uma pausa e refletir, e por um momento apreciar o trabalho que todos fizemos juntos. Para isso, vejamos como foi feita a moderação no Stack Overflow em Português, dividido por atividade, nos últimos 12 meses:

<sup><sub>***Alguns termos deixei em inglês, pois fiquei em dúvida sobre a tradução exata (não sei se existe um termo adequado/específico da comunidade para o mesmo).***</sub></sup>

```
Ação                                    Moderadores Comunidade¹ 
--------------------------------------- ----------- ---------- 
Usuários suspensos²                             22         12  
Usuários destruídos                             58          0  
Usuários deletados                              26          0  
Usuários contatados                             36          0  
Suspensões reconsideradas antes do término       1          0  
Usuários banidos da revisão                      1          0  
Revisões³: Edições sugeridas                   125      17159  
Revisões³: Votos para reabrir                   30       5577  
Revisões³: Publicações de baixa qualidade      213      22214  
Revisões³: Respostas tardias                     8       3189  
Revisões³: Primeiras publicações                95      17405  
Revisões³: Votos para fechar                    43      19101  
Tags mescladas                                  28          0  
Propostas de sinônimos de tag                   26          3  
Sinônimos de tag criados                        32          0  
Definição de coloração de sintaxe de tags        2          0  
Revisions redacted                              20          0  
Perguntas desprotegidas                          2          0  
Perguntas reabertas                            169        160  
Perguntas protegidas                            29        104  
Perguntas migradas                               7          1  
Perguntas mescladas                              9          0  
Perguntas sinalizadas⁴                          44       8681  
Perguntas fechadas                            5027       4937  
Sinalizações de perguntas tratadas⁴           2230       6495  
Publicações desbloqueadas                        1          4  
Publicações restauradas                        104       1193  
Publicações bloqueadas                          10        109  
Publicações apagadas⁵                         2778      22078  
Publicações levantadas à página principal        0       8716  
Escalações ao time de CMs                        5          0  
Comentários restaurados                         82          0  
Comentários sinalizados                        668       1281  
Comentários apagados⁶                         4994      13869  
Sinalizações de comentários tratadas          1736        213  
Respostas sinalizadas                           83      10015  
Sinalizações de respostas tratadas            6055       4043  
Comentários de um post movidos para o chat      48          0
```

#### Observações

¹ "Comunidade" se refere tanto a [membros do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users) *sem* [o diamante próximo ao seus nomes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), e ao sistema automático conhecido como [user #-1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1).

² O sistema suspende um usuário em três circunstâncias: quando o usuário é recriado depois de ser suspenso anteriormente, quando é recriado depois de ser destruído por *spam* ou abuso, ou quando a conta sofre uma suspensão em toda a rede.

³ Inclui todas as revisões que não foram puladas - ou seja, as duas revisões necessárias para as Edições Sugeridas contam como 2, pois o objetivo é indicar a frequência das ações de moderação. O mesmo se aplica a sinalizações, etc.

⁴ Inclui sinalizações de fechamento (mas *não* os votos para fechar ou reabrir).

⁵ Ignora os inúmeros casos em que a publicação é apagada automaticamente em resposta a alguma ação.

⁶ Inclui comentários apagados pelos próprios autores (que também considera algumas sinalizações de comentários que foram tratadas).

(Muito obrigado a [@Shog9](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9) por todo o trabalho com as queries SQL e por escrever o [post inicial](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378415/564240) para a comunidade.)

Comment: Nicolas, I was trying to translate, but found some terms difficult, such as "suspensions lifted early" - does it mean an user was suspended but the suspension was revoked/cancelled before its ending date? Even if I'm correct, I don't know if the mods use a specific term for that in portuguese, and I didn't want to guess them. The same applies for other items in the stats table (they have translations, but I don't know if mods have a specific term in portuguese). Would it be acceptable to make a partial translation, leaving these terms for others to translate (or not translated at all?)

Comment: @hkotsubo Thank you for translating it! I met this term for the first time as well when I was translating it to Russian. I think you are right, it means canceled suspensions. For the Russian language most of the other terms are ordinary or they listed in our [translation glossary](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1135/6), so I do not know if you guys have them in your glossary or not.

Comment: Well, I decided to leave some terms in English, hoping that someone comes with a proper translation :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo usei a tua tradução para o [Portuguese Language](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/320/153), obrigado.

Comment: @JorgeB. Fique à vontade para melhorá-la. Eu fiz algumas adaptações no texto, em vez de tentar uma tradução mais literal, então posso ter cometido algum equívoco...

Comment: O único que falta traduzir é "*Revisions redacted*". A tradução literal seria "*Revisões redigidas*", mas eu gostaria de saber exatamente o que isso vem a ser, pois esse acho que deve ser o único que ou desconheço ou esqueci o que era.

Comment: @VictorStafusa em resumo simples: apagar a senha que o sujeito largou no post.