# 2019: moderação do site em números

Tags: debate, moderação, estatísicas

I would appreciate the translation this question.

---

I would like to share with you a moderation statistics report for Stack Overflow in Portuguese.

A distinguishing characteristic of Stack Exchange sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
>   -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges 
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.  And what could be more festive than a big pile of numbers?  So here is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Stack Overflow in Portuguese over the past 12 months:

```
                  Action                  Moderators Community¹
----------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                          65         11 
Users destroyed³                          83         0
Users deleted                             61         0
Users contacted                           114        0
User review-bans lifted early             1          0
User banned from review                   9          0
Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue     176        16335
Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue        349        9894
Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue  82         15723
Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue        4          3186
Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue         30         18391
Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue        64         20550
Tags merged                               12         0
Tag synonyms proposed                     12         2
Tag synonyms created                      13         0
Tag highlight language set                1          0
Revisions redacted                        30         0
Questions unprotected                     1          0
Questions reopened                        299        166
Questions protected                       18         82
Questions migrated                        2          4
Questions merged                          3          0
Questions flagged⁵                        214        7608
Questions closed                          12426      4168
Question flags handled⁵                   3412       4399
Posts unlocked                            11         20
Posts undeleted                           112        1044
Posts locked                              35         120
Posts deleted⁶                            3056       27818
Posts bumped                              0          8616
Escalations to the CM team                23         0
Comments undeleted                        76         0
Comments flagged                          671        735
Comments deleted⁷                         2855       8762
Comment flags handled                     1288       118
Bounties canceled                         9          0
Answers flagged                           315        8702
Answer flags handled                      6878       2138
All comments on a post moved to chat      49         0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Stack Overflow in Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? I posted a similar report here last year: [2018: moderação do site em números](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7567/17539)...
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222019%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341507/2019-a-year-in-closing)

We wish you all a happy new year...

---

(A lot of thanks to [@Shog9](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9) for all the hard work with  SQL queries and writing the [initial post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392550/) for the community.)

Comment: Nicolas, você como gerente de comunidade responsável pelo SOpt, como avalia esses números?

Comment: @Woss Para ser honesto, estou um pouco preocupado que os mods tenham fechado quase três vezes mais perguntas do que toda a comunidade. Quero dizer, é muito diferente dos outros nossos sites. O que você acha dos números?

Comment: Esse ponto em específico é algo que foi discutido literalmente o ano inteiro. O fato de causar preocupação só agora mostra que a SE está completamente omissa nos problemas da comunidade.

Comment: Eu acho um valor justo dado o momento da comunidade. Sem eles o site estaria um caos absoluto. E isso também foi amplamente discutido o ano inteiro...

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky a sensação que temos é que não estamos dando conta de fechar, e que a comunidade simplesmente não fecha mais nada (tirando alguns usuários engajados). O site virou um mero helpdesk de problemas individuais, a grande maioria dos usuários que vieram com a promessa de um site com mais controle de qualidade (foi nossa bandeira no começo, para convidar pessoas e divulgar a rede) foi embora. Temos bons usuários engajados e preocupados com qualidade, mas é muito limitado em números. Diria ainda que considerando o tipo de coisa que vem sendo postada, precisariamos fechar bem mais.

Comment: Até comentamos certa vez (com um pouco de ironia, mas um fundo de verdade) que deveria chegar no ponto onde a pergunta começa fechada, e a comunidade teria que aprovar para liberar para respostas :)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky sim, nós estamos falando há bastante tempo que a comunidade quase não existe mais no SOpt. "Ninguém" se importa mais com o site. Qual sua sugestão em relação a isto? Já viu esses números? https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/9591/2019-a-year-in-moderation. Me desculpe, você não tem nada a ver com isso, mas todos notam que está faltando ação ou até visão à SE para lidar com os muitos problemas encontrados na rede hoje em dia.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky como disse o Bacco e bem, as perguntas deveriam entrar no site já fechadas. A qualidade das perguntas é cada vez menor. A maioria dos bons programadores afastou-se do site por causa disso.

Comment: E, para clarificar, eu particularmente votei -1 na pergunta porque não vi um objetivo definido na publicação. Para mim pareceu que a publicação foi uma tentativa de mostrar que o trabalho está sendo feito, mas a única coisa feita com a execução de uma SQL. Claramente os números não foram analisados, não foram comparados com os problemas relatados durante o ano e não foram localizados para a realidade atual da comunidade. Resumindo: números avulsos que demonstram nada.

Comment: É a mesma publicação, não se deu nem ao trabalho de reaproveitar a tradução feita em [2018: moderação do site em números](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7567/5878). Literalmente executou a SQL e colou o resultado aqui. Com que moral a SE acha que pode vir e pedir [mais proatividade da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7719/5878) com um comportamento assim?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky The moderators ♦ closed 3x more, because these moderators care more than the community (users) itself, the quality of the questions is terrible, we have become a helpdesk instead. **In short:** there are too few people doing much for the community (such moderators and a few contributors), too many users doing too little and just coming to ask or moderating (I speak of the power that some ordinary users have) very wrong... It's just my opinion of what I notice on most network websites.

Comment: Mais uma vez, tantas perguntas sem resposta.

Comment: É sempre assim? Nossa opinião só conta se dissermos coisas bonitinhas, caso os membros da comunidade se manifestem informando problemas reais esses serão sumariamente ignorados? Agora entendo o porque a maioria dos especialista e superusuários deixaram o site, quem ganha não se importa com quem trabalha de graça.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Sim, sempre assim. E depois criam essas pseudo-perguntas no Meta cuspindo alguns números *para inglês ver*.

Comment: кому платят, все равно, кто работает бесплатно.

Comment: Mais de 16000 perguntas fechadas, de um total de cerca de 42000 (segundo [este post](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8110/112052)), isso dá **quase 40%** das perguntas fechadas. Isso porque não há muitos usuários ativos com mais de 3000 pontos usando seus votos de fechamento, senão a porcentagem seria ainda maior. O que a SE está fazendo pra nos ajudar a melhorar esses - e outros - números (se é que ela realmente acha que é um problema)?

Comment: @hkotsubo Obrigado! Uma observação muito interessante. Você poderia publicá-lo como uma pergunta? Nesse caso, poderei responder com alguns dos meus pensamentos.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Essa já é uma pergunta sobre os números da moderação; acredito ser desnecessário criar outra sobre o mesmo assunto. Você pode responder nessa mesma.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Done: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8123/112052

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se é compreensível a você Nicolas ou ao time da SE, ou mesmo quem seja de cultura lusofônica mas não seja brasileiro, nossa educação(Brasil) passou por um período de quase duas décadas de degradação deliberada e os jovens que foram atingindo por esse processo estão chegando ou estão em vias de chegar a vida acadêmica.

Acredito estarmos vivendo um cenário diferenciado das outras comunidades. É como se uma parcela significativa da população tivesse sido criada para ser figurante do filme [Os Selvagens da Noite(The Warriors)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080120/), essas pessoas estão com sérios problemas em:

- incapacidade de seguir regras.
- incapacidade de concatenar idéias.
- incapacidade de se expressar de forma clara.
- incapacidade de fazer uso racional da língua nativa.
- incapacidade de projetar ópticas de pensamentos.
- incapacidade de fazer autocriticas.
- incapacidade de aceitar erros.
- incapacidade de se auto-corrigir.
- incapacidade de entender e adequar-se a protocolos de comportamento.
- incapacidade de compartilhar.
- incapacidade de visualizar benefícios comunitários ao invés do próprio.
- comportamento destrutivo.
- comportamento infantil dentro dum meio técnico.
- comportamento autoindulgente.

Dentre outros comportamentos sistemáticos.

Com as atuais regras de funcionamento isso está sendo um problema  para a nossa comunidade. Tudo que eu e meus colegas desejam é a Rede Stack Exchange de mais atenção para o Stack Overflow em Português e ouça nossas solicitações para que possamos realizarmos com sucesso nossa missão de criar o maior banco de dados de perguntas e resposta sobre linguagens de programação.

---

*Pessoalmente* tenho uma requisição a SE. Eu gostaria que fossem diminuídos a quantidade de votos comunitários para fechar e reabrir uma pergunta. Creio que passando de cinco para três votos os processos de moderação comunitária se tornariam mais ágeis e eficientes, dando uma sensação de maior controle para a comunidade e equilibrando esse número que o incomodou.

Por que isso?

Porque o número de usuários cujo a participação seja *ativa* e com *reputação suficiente* para abrir e fechar uma pergunta é reduzido o que força aos moderadores eleitos a tomar para si toda essa responsabilidade. É a possibilidade de equilibrar os números que lhe chamou a atenção.

---

*Como comunidade*, o que nós membros do Stack Overflow em Português estamos pedimos é que a SE olhe para nós e nos ouça pois estamos passando por uma turbulência social e essa turbulência se reflete no site. O prognóstico é de melhora no futuro, pois medidas estão sendo tomadas, mas no momento nos ouçam.

Comment: Sou novato aqui na página e espero não estar a *pegar o bonde andando e sentar na janelinha(johnny-come-lately)*. Estou aberto a discordância e qualquer apontamento em favor e contrário a minha opinião só vem a enriquecer.

Comment: Sobre os 3 votos pra fechar parece bom, mas do jeito que tem gente descompromissada e abusando conscientemente do sistema, vão reabrir muita porcaria, de qq forma +1 pela colocação toda, principalmente sobre as 2 décadas de destruição.

Comment: Todo o sistema de fechamento deveria ser revisto, por exemplo deixar as pessoas votarem depois de já fechado pra reforçar que é ruim mesmo, que não é só uma ou 5 pessoas considerando aquilo, includindo outro moderadores, separar quem votou em qual motivo, ter formas de acompanhar o andamento da pergunta quando a pessoa quer dar uma chance antes de votar, algo melhor que o favorito, e talvez até o voto condicional, só para citar algumas coisas, mas sabemos que nada será feito, nem discutido seriamente, mesmo no meta.SE.

Comment: Eu não acho que a culpa seja essencialmente da "nova geração". Para mim, é mais o fato da plataforma não ser resiliente o suficiente para se adequar às mudanças de comportamento dos usuários, sempre visando o melhor deles. O público alvo de quando o SO foi criado é diferente do atual, isso é fato, mas cabe a plataforma mudar para se adequar a ambos e não se limitar aos antigos porque "antes funcionava bem".

Comment: Eu vi e entendi que não tem para quem recorrer pedindo por melhorias. Eu não recebi uma resposta do Nicolas nem para dizer que *estou equivocado e não entendo nada sobre o Brasil e a cultura brasileira*. Agradeço aos três pelos comentários. A opinião e posicionamento de vocês para mim são muito importantes.

Comment: "*nossa educação(Brasil) passou por um período de quase duas décadas de degradação deliberada*" - Na verdade, ela nunca foi lá grande coisa. Há duas décadas atrás, já era um desastre.

Comment: @Bacco e Augusto, pelo jeito mudar de 5 pra 3 votos de fechamento é menos complicado do que pensei, vejam: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341810/401803 - infelizmente não terei tempo nos próximos dias pra criar uma pergunta com essa discussão, mas o caminho parece ser "simples"

Comment: @hkotsubo já publiquei https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8132/devemos-baixar-nosso-limite-de-votos-para-fechar-e-reabrir-perguntas

Comment: @hkotsubo eu sou contra. Não acha 3 pra fechar quase nunca, e sempre tem um bando que reabre porcaria na fila.

Comment: @Bacco Com certeza a reabertura indevida é um efeito colateral a ser considerado, mas se for uma quantidade pequena e aumentar os fechamentos, talvez compense. De qualquer forma, a pergunta já foi criada e podemos discutir mais detalhadamente lá - infelizmente ficarei offline nas próximas horas, mas já adianto que acho que vale a pena ao menos tentar (desde que haja a possibilidade de desfazer a mudança rapidamente pro caso de não dar certo)