# Devemos diminuir a quantidade de votos necessários para fechar e reabrir perguntas?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, status-pronto

Acabei de ser informado que o SO abaixou o limite de votos necessários para fechar e reabrir perguntas, foi modificado de cinco votos para três votos. [Aqui](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391832/we-re-lowering-the-close-reopen-vote-threshold-from-5-to-3-for-good).

Foi feito um [experimento](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388313/experiment-ended-closing-and-reopening-happens-at-3-votes-for-the-next-30-day) por 30 dias onde o limite de votos necessários para reabrir e fechar perguntas foi baixado de cinco para três votos e os resultados do impacto gerado nessa comunidade(https://www.stackoverflow.com) estão [aqui](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390083/threshold-experiment-results-closing-editing-and-reopening-all-become-more-eff), o experimento foi considerado um sucesso tanto que foi implementado no SO.

As outras comunidades estão se questionando sobre baixar o limite votos de reabertura e fechamento

- https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1478/can-we-get-the-close-vote-threshold-lowered-to-3
- https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3260/can-we-get-the-close-and-reopen-voting-thresholds-lowered-to-3
- https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2057/is-it-possible-to-reduce-the-number-of-close-votes-needed-for-certain-types-of-c
- https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4687/cancelling-election-lets-try-something-else-testing-three-vote-question-clos

*A proposta é baixar o atual limite de **cinco** votos para **três*** votos com o objetivo de melhorar a eficácia e dar agilidade aos processos de fechamento e abertura de questões.

Atualmente o nosso quadro de usuários ativos com reputação suficiente para fechar e reabrir perguntas é baixo tornando esse processo demorado por parte dos comunitários, fazendo com que esse trabalho seja em grande parte feito pelos moderadores.

Então a proposta de três votos para fechar e reabrir perguntas é uma medida que busca adequar a dinâmica do site a nossa realidade acelerando o processo de moderação visando qualidade ao facilitar a integração entre as diferentes partes da comunidade.

Caso a comunidade entre em consenso e estejamos a favor, [aqui nesse link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341896/608272) está o passo para a moderação solicitar a mudança desse limite.

---

## Atualização

[Será feito um teste](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8591/112052), no qual o SOpt e mais alguns outros sites da rede terão o limite diminuído para três votos. O teste terá início em 6 de maio de 2021 e durará 45 dias.

Todos os detalhes estão no [anúncio oficial no meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364007/401803), mas acho que vale citar os dados que serão analisados após o teste:

- se houve aumento nas porcentagens de fechamentos/reaberturas feitos pela comunidade (ou seja, não-moderadores)
- *ou* aumento nos votos de fechamento/reabertura por moderadores, mas nos casos em que era o último voto faltante (ou seja, quando for o terceiro voto)
- aumento pequeno ou mínimo nas "*close/reopen wars*"

Comment: É importante votar e também é importante dar sua opinião. Afinal é a **nossa** comunidade

Comment: Totalmente! Essa é uma das primeiras coisas que vejo a SE indo na direção certa. Aqui é muito mais necessário que um site grande com o SOen. Acho que devíamos testar os números, tentar 1, 2 ou 3 votos e ver o que acontece. Penso como o Bacco que não gosta de fechar sozinho e acho que até outras medidas poderiam ser tomadas para melhorar isto (permitir voto mesmo depois de algo fechado para reforçar a intenção da comunidade é um exemplo.

Comment: Pode ser assimétrico? :) 1 voto pra fechar e 3 para reabrir? :D Porque vai acontecer muito do AP e um pretendente a responder querer votar para reabrir por isso deveria ser no mínimo 3. Em geral a comunidade não está ligando para a qualidade, não querem aparecer como fechadores então tá raro ter mais que um voto para fechar. O processo é assimétrico por natureza, por isso minha proposta seria ter assimetria. A questão da escolha é se queremos mais qualidade ou mais quantidade.

Comment: @Maniero se puder assimétrico muda tudo. Eu baixaria só pra fechar. Poste  como resposta pro pessoal poder votar.

Comment: Não teria como verificar com o CM se esse processo pode assimétrico?

Comment: @AugustoVasques pelo que eu li tudo que foi feito é simétrico, mas... perguntar não custa (só talvez demore pra ter resposta, estou aguardando retorno faz dias sobre outros assuntos). EDIT: o JNat está de volta

Comment: Seria bom saber que chegaríamos mais rápido a um consenso.

Comment: O @JNat verificará para nós se a assimetria é possível.

Comment: @Bacco a hora que tiver uma resposta, me avise.

Comment: @Bacco Vi que uma pergunta foi reaberta só com 3 votos (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/272332) - já é oficial ou foi apenas um teste?

Comment: @hkotsubo, acho que foi teste. Olha essa aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/446335/como-usar-o-stitchappclientconfiguration-do-mongodb-stitch-browser-sdk-no-javasc#comment857681_446335 continua pendente com três votos.

Comment: Quando me achava somente mais uma voz fraca entre muitas outras vozes mais fortes que a minha fui ouvido. Que esse apelo só venha a agregar.

Answer (score 17):

Eu gosto da ideia, mas precisa pensar bem e principalmente testar e ver o resultado, não podemos optar em definitivo sem ver o que acontece, se vai melhorar o andamento da comunidade.

## Está difícil fechar algo pela comunidade

Vemos que [os moderadores estão com muita carga para fechar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8123/101). Ao contrário do que alguns pensam moderadores não gostam de fechar, é feito com certa amargura. Mas a comunidade não está muito ativa mais, ou porque tem pouca gente participando mesmo, ou porque estão um pouco apáticos, ou porque alguns consideram que não são capazes de avaliar, ou porque não querem ser associados como fechadores até porque isto acaba puxando votos negativos por vingança ou outras animosidades, ou porque acham que o SOpt é um local do tipo Yahoo! Respostas ou Facebook e qualquer coisa serve.

Essa mudança pode fazer os moderadores evitarem um pouco o fechamento.

Então eu acho que deveríamos testar com 1 voto. Também com 2 votos (talvez o que funcione melhor). E quem sabe até com 3 votos.

## Assimetria

Se puder ser assimétrico melhor. Eu sei, parece forçado, mas o processo atual é assimétrico por natureza. Justiça é quando se considera as diferenças.

Em geral o AP pode votar pra reabrir sua pergunta. Não sei porque isto é permitido, não deveria acontecer, com qualquer um, talvez até um moderador não deveria poder votar para reabrir sua pergunta, ainda que em geral moderadores tendem a não forçar uma situação de poder para benefício próprio. Mas como é permitido temos 1 voto quase automático para reabrir, até pessoas com menos de 3000 pontos pode fazer isto na sua pergunta, não faz sentido.

Se isto mudar já ajuda, mas se não mudar 1 voto para reabrir é muito pouco, teria que ser assimétrico.

Em geral sempre tem alguém que quer responder, em geral de boa fé, mas ou a pessoa só está querendo os pontos daquilo ou acha que qualquer coisa merece ser respondida, mesmo com uma resposta ruim. Muitas dessas pessoas não aprendem porque elas já deram respostas que foram rechaçadas pelo AP porque a pergunta era ruim mesmo, não dava para responder. Isto causa muito ruído.

Quando a pessoa quer responder ela não liga para as regras, e ela vota para reabrir. Então 2 votos para reabrir é pouco.

Então eu acho que para reabrir precisa de no mínimo 3 votos.

Se a SE disser que isto pode ser feito aí acho que achamos a solução perfeita fácil.

## Voto de moderador

A diminuição pode trazer menos trabalho para moderadores. Mas pode trazer um peso maior. Eu prevejo que moderadores vão ter que fechar perguntas reabertas indevidamente, e isto pode ser ruim, pode por algumas pessoas contra a moderação porque "a comunidade reabriu" e o moderador foi lá e foi contra. Então pode tirar um peso e por outro, que pode ser pior.

## Pode não ser suficiente

Acontece que o maior problema que temos é algo ser respondido antes de ter o primeiro voto para fechar. E quando isto não acontece é porque um moderador fechou e não teve um voto da comunidade. Isto não vai mudar.

Ainda assim acho que vale o teste.

## Autor não poderia votar pra reabrir

Acho isto importante porque ele está "legislando em causa própria".

## Votos deveriam ser aceitos mesmo depois de ter consumado fechamento

Um dos problemas de ter menos votos é diminuir legitimidade, como acontece um pouco quando o moderador fecha e ninguém mais pode fechar, nem mesmo outro moderador.

## Vamos testar com 1, 2 ou 3 votos?

Depois tomamos uma decisão definitiva.

[Já tem site operando com 1 voto](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/655).

Comment: Um voto significa que o próprio autor reabre, não? Três acho que vai ser tarde demais. **Se é pra testar eu começaria com 2**, que atende um pouco do que eu comentei e não piora tanto a "farra do reopen" (que, infelizmente raramente tem tido razão legítima para acontecer). Se pudesse ser assimétrico eu mandaria algo como 2 pra fechar, e no minimo 3 pra reabrir (4 reabrir se o autor puder votar).

Comment: Acho um bom começo. De qualquer forma tirar o voto do autor é outra questão que deveria ser endereçada. Se for assimétrico eu mandaria 1 para fechar e 4 para reabrir, mas aceito 3 para reabrir, acho que aceitaria 2 para reabrir se tirar o voto do autor.

Comment: Se tirar o voto do autor é um caso a se pensar se não der  vai incitar guerra de Abertura/Fechamento.

Comment: @AugustoVasques é o que eu falei de por peso no moderador ter que ir lá e refechar algo que a comunidade reabriu, não sei o que é pior, isso ou moderador ter que fechar 75% das perguntas (não sei se essa estatística é o mod ter fechado sozinho ou ter dado vinculante, e se o vinculante inclui o 5o. voto que no fundo o mod votou como um usuário normal).

Comment: O @JNat verificará para nós se a assimetria é possível.

Comment: **Votos deveriam ser aceitos mesmo depois de ter consumado fechamento** realmente seria um bom mecanismo, evitaria reabertura por algo que claramente foi considerado ruim por uma grande variedade de pessoas. O fato de limitar a N votos faz com que não se meça a seriedade do problema. Só acho que é meio utópico, pois provavelmente envolveria reescrever essa parte do sistema (ou não, quem sabe... vai que a implementação atual favorece...)

Comment: @Bacco sim, esta é a direção certa se quer dar voz para a comunidade, por que ela deve se calar depois da ação ter ocorrido? Não acho que mudará muito, mas mudará um pouco. Muitos não vão votar depois que já está fechado, mas quem está interessado na qualidade fará isto. Acho isto importante inclusive para ter mais de um moderador votando e demonstrar que não foi a vontade de uma pessoa. E acho que será mais difícil implantarem porque muda o sistema. Mas eu achava que não dava para mudar fácil o número de votos por site. A Se pode estar querendo mudar um pouco a imagem.

Comment: Eu confesso que um voto para fechar me assusta um pouco... Ficaria com um pouco de receio de fechar algumas perguntas de maneira incorreta com o único voto necessário. A votação me deixa mais tranquilo, tornando o processo um pouco menos "perigoso". Mas se abaixássemos o número de votos para 1, será que realmente seria um "voto"? Ainda sim, é sempre importante ter responsabilidade quando se vota para fechar a pergunta. [...] Enfim, na minha opinião, 2 ou 3 votos para fechar são um número ideal, com 4 ou 5 para reabrir, se a assimetria for permitida. :-)

Comment: Concordo com o @LuizFelipe. 1 voto para fechar acho pouco. Poderá, por um lado, haver fechamento precipitado e, pior ainda, por motivos "maus", por outro, aumenta a responsabilidade o que poderá  retrair o voto(vejam o exemplo do Bacco). Definitivamente não faz sentido o AP poder votar para reabrir a sua pergunta.

Comment: Eu concordo que um voto é pouco e cria riscos. Por outro lado qual é o nosso maior problema hoje? Muitas perguntas ruins que não são fechadas antes que crie um problema maior? Não a toa algumas pessoas cogitam utopicamente (por enquanto) que as perguntas iniciassem fechadas e precisariam ser abertas já que o mais comum é algo ter que ser fechado. Por isso não seria tantos casos errados e e mesmo estes poderiam ser corrigidos, seria melhor um moderador ter que reabrir algo fechado indevidamente do que ter que fechar tanta coisa. Ainda tem um outro lado que eu temo.

Comment: Mesmo hoje ainda falta até mesmo um voto para fechar. Pode ser que moderadores ainda tenham que fechar boa parte das perguntas mesmo com um voto para a comunidade fechar. Fico pensando se tem solução real para o estado que chegamos.

Comment: Acredito que 3 seja um bom número ou até 2, 1 voto acho muito pouco

Comment: @Maniero A SE respondeu algo sobre a parte da Assimetria? Se é possível? Implementaremos isso?

Comment: @danieltakeshi nada. Mas nesse altura não sei se faz diferença Quase ninguém vota em nada mais, melhor deixar como está.

Comment: Eu acho que ajudaria, não solucionaria o problema. Muitas vezes eu vejo perguntas com 3 ou 4 votos. Que não são fechadas por este motivo

Comment: @danieltakeshi eu esqueço de dar uma olhada nas que estão largadas, preciso lembrar disso.

Answer (score 9):

Minha opinião pessoal: se forem três votos simétricos (fechar e reabrir),

NÃO. Não acho que vá dar certo.

(mas nessas alturas do campeonato, se quiserem testar)

Eu como moderador não me sinto confortável em fechar perguntas sozinho. Só que simplesmente não aparecem votos de fechar da comunidade, salvo raras exceções.

Ja é um alívio quando um vota, para pelo menos "puxar a fila". Raro quando aparecem dois, o terceiro nem se fala.

Acontece que o sistema é simétrico. Se baixa para fechar, baixa para reabrir, e gente reabrindo sem ler na fila de reabertura tem de sobra, além de outros problemas moderatórios que infelizmente não dá pra tratar aqui (relacionados a pessoas trabalhando com interesse que vai além da gamificação, que deveria ser "dentro das regras" apenas).

Se fizermos essa mudança, vai favorecer o lado que cria problema, e não o que resolve.

Comment: Em um adendo, apesar de duvidar que façam algo assim, mas acho que neste caso o AP nem poderia votar.

Comment: Vai continuar do mesmo jeito só o limiar de votos que muda.

Comment: Vejo razão nesse pensamento, vamos ver o que pode ser feito.

Comment: Desculpa ai @Bacco mas tive que votar. O argumento do Maniero é forte.

Comment: @AugustoVasques não tem do que se desculpar, o debate é para isso.

Comment: Como é um implementação nova pode ser que se consiga que não seja simétrico aqui. Até podem fazer do SOpt um teste a 3 para fechar e 5 para reabrir. Não custa pedir.

Comment: O @JNat verificará para nós se a assimetria é possível.

Answer (score 5):

Como alguns de vocês já leram no [post no Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364007/testing-three-vote-close-and-reopen-on-13-network-sites), finalmente faremos um teste com vários sites, e [o Stack Overflow em Português é um deles](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8591/112052).

A partir de amanhã, mudaremos a configuração do site, e serão necessários apenas três votos para o fechamento e reabertura de perguntas. O teste terá a duração de 45 dias, e após o término deste período, a configuração voltará para cinco votos e os dados serão analisados. Após a análise, serão divulgados os resultados, e caso não haja impactos negativos, a configuração mudará em definitivo para três votos.

Daqui a algumas semanas, colocarei uma pergunta aqui no Meta, para saber como está o andamento do teste. Assim, teremos uma oportunidade para discutir os impactos.

Quanto à questão pendente sobre ter uma quantidade diferente de votos para fechar e reabrir, isso não será possível. Esperamos que o teste identifique situações que possam ser problemáticas e possam precisar de soluções diferentes. Por exemplo, se houver um grande aumento nas *close/reopen wars* porque se tornou mais fácil reabrir, uma discussão será necessária para ajudar todos a ficarem na mesma página sobre os critérios para fechar perguntas.

Não estou em posição de recomendar nada, já que não tenho o histórico dos problemas que vocês têm enfrentado e nem das tentativas anteriores de resolvê-los, mas não é nossa intenção causar mais impactos negativos com esta mudança.

O que posso dizer é que os moderadores não deveriam estar fazendo todo o trabalho aqui, e este teste terá pouca importância se eles continuarem responsáveis pela maior parte dos fechamentos. Vocês precisam de uma comunidade engajada em ajudar o site nos fechamentos, edições, análises, respostas e votos no conteúdo, para que todos possam separar o conteúdo bom do ruim.

Obrigado por esperar enquanto priorizávamos e preparávamos este teste. Há muito mais informações no [post original](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364007/testing-three-vote-close-and-reopen-on-13-network-sites), por favor leiam.

Comment: If someone would be so kind as to translate this for me, that would be appreciated! :)

Comment: To know more about our history (regarding mods doing the bulk of closures), a good starting point is [here](/q/8311/112052) and [here](/q/8123/112052). For short: the community is not active, only a few members still care about closing/reopening, editing and even voting. Most users don't care about the rules and post bad quality, off-topic questions, and many answer those questions (with even worse answers). So the mods, by closing most part of these bad questions, are responsible for avoiding things to get even worse.

Comment: Regarding our idea to have a different number of votes for closing and reopening, our rationale is that the OP can vote to reopen their own question (if they have the vote-to-close privilege), therefore - from our point of view - **the system is already asymetric** in those cases, as the OP will always want to reopen their questions.

Comment: I appreciate the clarification. One note, users need 250 reputation to actually vote to reopen (or close) their own question. So, if most questions come from very low rep users, there's no imbalance. Edits to the question after closure will put the question in the reopen queue but they don't cast votes. I also disagree that the OP (with sufficient reputation) is necessarily a poor judge of whether their question should be reopened. They're certainly biased but they get a vote, both ways.

Comment: I've just voted to close [this question](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/508075/112052). My vote was the third, but it wasn't closed. At what time exactly will the config be changed?

Comment: When I'm awake and actually change the site settings. It's 7am here.

Comment: My apologies. I thought the config change  would follow the "system day" (UTC). Please take your time - and let us know when everything is set.

Comment: We are looking forward to this feature. I believe that speeding up the opening and closing of questions will make it easier for less experienced users to understand the dynamics of how the site works. Where we will have more dynamic interactions between question authors and the community, aiming to improve the quality of questions.