# Teste de diminuição de votos necessários para fechar e reabrir perguntas (de 5 para 3). Vamos participar!

Tags: debate, perguntas-fechadas

Atualmente são necessários 5 votos para fechar ou reabrir uma pergunta.

Devido à baixa participação da comunidade e ao aumento das perguntas problemáticas (que de acordo com as [regras do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/112052) devem ser fechadas), [houve uma discussão em janeiro de 2020](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8132/112052), sobre diminuir a quantidade necessária de votos para 3. No final nada mudou, *até agora*.

[Conforme anunciado no meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364007/401803), haverá um teste no qual alguns sites (incluindo o SOpt) terão o limite baixado de 5 para 3 votos, tanto para fechamento quanto para reabertura.

**O teste terá início em 6 de maio de 2021, e durará 45 dias.** Depois disso, o limite voltará para 5 e a SE analisará os dados do período.

No nosso caso, é importante notar que inicialmente eles pretendem analisar o seguinte:

- se houve aumento nas porcentagens de fechamentos/reaberturas feitos pela comunidade (ou seja, não-moderadores)
- *ou* aumento nos votos de fechamento/reabertura por moderadores, mas nos casos em que é o último voto faltante (ou seja, quando for o terceiro voto)
- aumento pequeno ou mínimo nas "*close/reopen wars*"

Também vale ressaltar este trecho:

> *The effect that we're really hoping for is that the same number of people will still keep doing the same number of reviews which will lead to more closures or reopenings because there's only three people needed to get there.*

Em tradução livre:

> O que realmente esperamos é que a mesma quantidade de pessoas continuem com a mesma quantidade de análises, que levarão a mais fechamentos ou reaberturas, porque agora só precisarão de 3 pessoas para tal.

---

Enfim, o site tem muitos problemas, e um deles é que muitas perguntas fora do escopo não são fechadas a tempo, atraindo respostas ruins que não contribuem com o objetivo do site, que é formar o repositório de conhecimento sobre programação. Acredito que este teste pode mostrar resultados positivos nesse sentido, mas **é necessário mais participação da comunidade**. Se você tem mais de 3000 pontos, use os seus votos de fechamento. Se tem pelo menos 15 pontos, [sinalize as perguntas problemáticas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) para que sejam fechadas.

Embora não trate da causa (o fato de muita gente não ler as regras e fazer perguntas fora do escopo) e sim do sintoma, ainda acho que é um teste válido e a SE só irá prosseguir se este mostrar resultados. E isso depende da participação de toda a comunidade.

---

Atualização (06/05/21):

Houve um [pequeno atraso por parte da SE](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8132#comment35461_8592), mas o teste já está valendo.

Comment: Quem tem menos de 3000 pontos pode sinalizar para fechar, que já é alguma ajuda.

Comment: Se essa mudança estimular a comunidade a participar mais, ótimo. Se a participação não aumentar, acho que não deve fazer tanta diferença 3 ou 5 votos, continuarão sendo as mesmas poucas pessoas tratando o problema.

Comment: Seria importante a comunidade fazer um esforço pelo menos esses dias para fechar tudo o que precisa com os 3 votos e não precisar dos moderadores, pro isso não deixe de votar logo de imediato.

Comment: Para quem não sabe é possível ver que tem votos pendentes: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tools. Nem todos possuem privilégio nessa página.

Comment: @bfavaretto discordo um pouco, se não aumentar a participação não resolve o real problema, mas ajuda a aliviar o sintoma, como já dito. Ao diminuir os votos necessários pra fechar e reabrir deve diminuir a quantidade de perguntas mal feitas abertas e facilitar a reabertura de perguntas arrumadas

Comment: @Costamilam o problema é que é tão raro "não moderadores ♦" pra fechar algo, é uma vez ou outra mesmo, que os dizeres do Bfavareto fazem sentido, a participação tem que aumentar pelo menos um pouco, mesmo que minima, para ter algum sinal de "alivio dos sintomas".

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não posso falar muito, não estou participando nem perguntando e respondendo, menos ainda moderando, só acompanho as vezes o chat e o meta. Sinceramente, nem dá vontade de voltar, a lista de perguntas recentes tem tanto conteúdo pouco elaborado (pra ser gentil), negativos e fechamentos que desanima

Comment: @Costamilam o conteúdo mal elaborado é o motivo dos negativos e fechamentos. Se tiver bem elaborado e esforço, mesmo que mínimo, então os demais "negativos" e "fechamentos" irão diminuir, nada é arbitrário (mesmo que as vezes/raramente aparece alguém usando mal os downvotes)

Comment: @bfavaretto fiz um teste esses dias, mas não tem jeito. Só pegando as perguntas muito runs e que não tem nem oque pensar pra fechar, depois de minutos costuma não ter votos pra fechar e em alguns casos aparece resposta ruim ou o "fiz pra você", depois de horas poucas conseguem 2 votos pra eu dar o final, e raro o que fecha sem mod intervir. Fim de semana foi trágico. Por enquanto estou martelando, mas como já disse antes estou preparando pra deixar pra lá, não tem mais o que fazer, a não ser o que a gente sabe que não será feito.

Comment: Ainda tem o defeito do usuário comum só poder dar 20 votos para fechar. Isso é uma assimetria, e junto com o AP poder votar, torna tudo complicado. Não dá para aceitar menos de 4 votos para reabrir, e mesmo 1 para fechar pode se mostrar complicado, pelo menos se não tirar o limite de votos.

Comment: Pois é, mal virou o dia e só tenho mais 6 votos. E não para de aparecer perguntas ruins...

Comment: A impressão que deu é que depois de um ou dois dias do pessoal tentando, desistiram mais que antes, parece que viram que não tem mais o que fazer. Eu até estava pensando em fazer puma postagem pedindo pra aumentar o limite de votos das pessoas mais ativas, mas nem vou fazer, não vai resolver, é algo que já está consolidado, pra mim o teste via mostrar que no SOpt tanto faz, ou a moderação continuará fechando quase tudo ou desistirá e virará a bagunça que eles desejam. Já sabemos que as pessoas cansaram, só o "começa fechado" resolveria.

Comment: eu gostei, e não tinha visto isso, achei que era algum bug :)

Answer (score 6):

Pelo que vi até agora em uma semana de experiência acho que posso dizer que aqui o teste não indica que reduzir a quantidade de votos soluciona o problema dos fechamento pela comunidade. E acho que após os 45 dias o resultado será até pior. Espero muito estar errado, mas infelizmente parece tarde demais para consertar, as pessoas já cansaram.

Hoje não deve ter nem meia dúzia de usuários que usam com a dedicação necessária para fazer isso funcionar. E é necessária mais dedicação porque tem poucas pessoas.

Veja bem, não estou reclamando das pessoas não participarem tanto, cada um sabe onde seu calo dói e não vejo isso como algo negativo. Negativo é a pessoa participar e fazer tudo errado, mas a pessoa ter tanto tempo para o SOpt é super normal.

Com a restrição de 24 votos diários por pessoa e ter tão poucas interessadas, com tempo e disposição de fazer fechamentos, a maioria do que deveria ser fechado fica aberto ou demora muito para fechar, o que ainda faz a moderação intervir antes.

Pode melhorar um pouco, mas a solução agora precisa ser mais radical. Além de ter poucas pessoas o volume de perguntas ruins é muito grande já que boa parte das pessoas que aparecem para perguntar não tem compromisso com o mínimo de qualidade ou não possuem noção alguma do que estão fazendo. Talvez as melhores vão para o SOen.

A solução deveria ser começar fechado e a comunidade abre se estiver em boas condições. Isso tiraria o peso da moderação ter que fechar tanto, a comunidade ter que se preocupar com tudo, e poderia se concentrar no que importa, fazer um trabalho melhor no que é bom ou salvável. Mas sabemos que isso não acontecerá, portanto o teste para nós não indica um caminho de solução.

Sem a SE realmente disposta a fazer o que precisa, ouvir a comunidade de verdade, e não ficar só no discurso, não haverá melhora, ficaremos fazendo um trabalho nada nobre em vez de contribuir para que as pessoas programem melhor.

Comment: Eu ainda ia questionar a questão dos votos limitados a 20 pra fechar. Teve uma noite, quando resetou para 24 votos, eu comecei a votar para fechar e antes mesmo da 1 da manhã, 14 votos meus já tinham sido dados. E quando acordei na manha seguinte, antes do meio dia, meus votos ficaram em zero, e tive que esperar até a noite pra poder votar. Mas pelo que voce disse, a quantidade de votos nem é o problema, mas sim a quantidade de pessoas  ativas relizando essa atividade moderadora. Confesso que fiquei um pouco triste porque achei que teriamos mais usuários engajados na causa e bons resultados.

Comment: Se não tivesse o limite até que meia dúzia de usuários resolvia parte do problema

Comment: Não entendi direito. Não tenho acesso às ferramentas de moderação para ver quantos fechamentos estão pendentes no total, consigo ver apenas minha fila. A quantidade de perguntas fechadas pela comunidade e de perguntas com fechamento pendente não melhoraram?

Comment: @RafaelTavares a minha percepção é que é não melhorou, eu deixei muita coisa pra comunidade e fechar e está difícil receber 3 votos, principalmente pela limitação de votos que pode dar, então eu já não estou mais segurando fechamento, até porque a demora causa problema. Alguns casos deixar pra comunidade até fechará, mas tarde demais. Então não melhorou significativamente e não vai resolver o problema.

Comment: @RafaelTavares Talvez tenha algum aumento na quantidade de fechamentos, mas como já disse, estamos tratando o sintoma e não a causa, então mesmo com a diminuição pra 3 votos ainda é insuficiente porque são poucos os que têm votado (fora a limitação de 24 votos diários), e não trata a causa raiz, que é o fato de muita gente não saber (ou não querer) fazer uma pergunta dentro do escopo (e passa por todos os problemas que já falamos tantas vezes, como a própria SE não ter interesse em resolver isso, etc). Ou seja, se manter em 3 votos, provavelmente será algo que "ajuda, mas não resolve"

Comment: No meta deveria reduzir pra 1 ou no máximo 2, está 5. Ok, é só um teste então não é importante, mas seria um teste mais completo. Eles errarem é normal, errar muito eu até entendo, mas quando junta com não ouvir a comunidade se torna um enorme problema.

Comment: Fui pego de surpresa pela mudança ontem (sumi por alguns meses e perdi o anúncio). Não sou contra a mudança, mas sinceramente aqui no SOpt não acho que faça muita diferença. A limitação na quantidade de votos para fechar atrapalha muito os pouquíssimos usuários que fecham perguntas ativamente. Na prática acho que os moderadores vão continuar carregando o peso dos fechamentos. E sobre reabertura de questões me parece que o impacto foi nulo. A diferença é que agora as questões fechadas vão ficar empacadas em 2 votos para reabrir ao invés de 3 ou 4...

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly é mais ou menos isso, só não diria que a reabertura foi nula, apenas muito pequena. Se agora reabre oque deveria, ótimo, se agora reabre o que continua com problema, criamos uma situação ruim que não existia ou era muito menor.

Comment: Maniero, eu quis dizer que o impacto na quantidade de reaberturas foi nula (ao menos é minha impressão, tenho certeza que no fim dos testes teremos os números saberemos melhor). Como usuário gostaria de ver um aumento no número de - boas - perguntas editadas, respondidas e reabertas. Não acho que a comunidade vai passar a forçar a rebertura de perguntas ruins. Diferente do SOen não vi muitas guerras de fechamento / reabertura por aqui. Prevejo que o terceiro voto hoje continuará tão raro quanto o quinto voto era no passado. Usuários que dão o terceiro voto de reabertura, quem eles são?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly isso não vai acontecer, todo mundo cansou, o site deveria ter ferramentas pra facilitar o trabalho burocrático e as pessoas se concentrar no que não dá para automatizar. Não há mais interesse no site, ele já tem a massa necessária, qualidade não importa mais, e sempre tem um trouxa pra fazer de graça o trabalho braçal. Mas não tem mais como antes. A comunidade não vai forçar abertura de perguntas ruins, mas algumas pessoas vão. O AP vota, um interessado em responder de forma ruim mesmo vota e um do grupo desse cara ou então alguém em fila de análise que vota sem ler nada, são 3

Comment: Oi Maniero, concordo plenamente contigo sobre todos os problemas do site e da Stack Exchange. Dito isso reforço que não estou preocupado com o número de reaberturas escalar. Como você mesmo colocou a comunidade anda apática. Não querendo tocar fogo na situação, mas eu ficaria feliz até em ver um ou outro caso de AP + Quem Respondeu + algum usuário alheio votando para reabrir uma pergunta borderline. Uma eventual rebelião aqui ou ali envolvendo 3 usuários de 3k+ reputação mostraria ao menos que ao menos o pessoal está vivo e usando as poucas ferramentas que temos.

Comment: By the way, um pouco off-topic, mas abri uma dúzia de perguntas em Fevereiro. Todas elas foram bem votadas e a grande maioria delas podem ser respondidas traduzindo alguma coisa do SOEn. O engajamento foi baixíssimo, a maioria das perguntas ficaram sem resposta. Chegamos em um ponto que não só não temos usuários para moderar, parece que temos poucos usuários até para responder (ao menos para responder perguntas um pouco menos triviais). O site realmente está sofrendo uma morte horrível por abandono (não dos mods, mas dos próprios usuários e da SE).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly sim, ninguém liga mais para o site, eu estou nas últimas, quero só cumprir alguns objetivos. Ele deixou de ser relevante. O SOen também (em menor grau, salva alguma coisa aqui e ali mas tem que se esforçar pra achar), ele vale pelo conteúdo antigo. Faz tempo que eu falo que o modelo não é sustentável como startup q precisa fazer dinheiro, precisa de volume não de qualidade. Nesse ponto a Wikipedia acertou, mas tem um software ruim e um modelo ultrapassado sob certos aspectos, mas é outro assinto.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Eu tenho visto a fila de reabertura com mais frequência ultimamente e vejo que a maioria das perguntas (praticamente todas, na verdade) não é melhorada o suficiente para ser reaberta. Então o problema (no caso de reabertura) talvez não seja a quantidade de votos, mas sim a falta de entendimento das pessoas, para deixarem a pergunta dentro do escopo. Cai no problema do próprio site não guiar melhor os usuários **e** da maioria ter dificuldade/preguiça de ler os milhares de links que já existem. Mas enfim, vou esperar os resultados do teste pra poder opinar melhor...

Comment: @hkotsubo é comum o cara mudar 3 palavras e achar que agora tá bom. E é aquela coisa, se tiver que explicar para cada um o que ele deve fazer para arrumar, e falar de novo, porque a pessoa não entende, de primeira, em geral nem de segunda ou terceira, quase sempre nunca entenderá, não sei o que ela está tentando fazer na programação, e é um trabalho ingrato, não ajuda ninguém, é perda de tempo, não é nobre, hoje em dia quase sempre só se dispõe fazer quem aparece de vez em quando e faz pontualmente ou quem não sabe fazer e não ajuda de fato.

Comment: O maior problema é que hoje não temos muitas perguntas feitas por programadores (mesmo em aprendizado), é só curiosos que não tem noção do que estão fazendo (e não falo só de programação). Fora as muitas perguntas que são "insalváveis" não importa o que melhore. Quero ver se endereço algo sobre as duplicatas que nem são duplicatas oficiais, ou seja, já perguntaram 500 vezes, não adianta marcar como duplicata e não adianta dar uma resposta porque é quase um erro de digitação (sem ser, é só a pessoa que não sabe o básico), é só ela pedindo para alguém falar debugarem pra ela. Não ensina.

Comment: @hkotsubo, talvez seu comentário (e o meu) sejam mais pertinentes na pergunta do Luiz Felipe (https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8600/100). Hoje a grande maioria das perguntas são muito ruins, os mods estão tendo que bater o martelo com mais frequência e infelizmente não dá tempo de fazer uma análise tão profunda de cada questão. Eu acho que na maioria dos casos você está correto, porém também vejo várias perguntas aproveitáveis e com boas respostas sendo fechadas e nunca mais sendo reabertas.

Comment: Minha linha de pensamento (que talvez não vá sempre de encontro ao consenso da comunidade e certamente não deve ser adotada como *guideline*) não mudou muito desde a época do Beta. Acredito que se a pergunta atende minimamente aos critérios do site, se recebeu ao menos uma resposta correta e didática, e, principalmente, se existem boas chances de alguém ter o mesmo problema e cair na resposta correta pelo Google, então devemos manter o conteúdo. Quando estou revisando algo na fila (algo de fato já não faço faz um bom tempo), eu sempre abro a página e tento ver o todo.

Comment: Conforme meu primeiro comentário, não recomendo nada disso como guideline para o site, mas sinceramente admito que costuma fazer pequenas edições e responder questões *borderline* quando julgo que existem boas chances de outros iniciantes encontrarem aquela pergunta no Google. Conforne o que o Maniero falou, hoje evito responder a duplicata número 64 do aluno tendo problemas, por exemplo, perdendo input ao misturar `Scanner.next()` / `Scanner.nextLine()` e `Scanner.nextInt()`, mas também já desisti de tentar fechar todas as duplicadas e criar perguntas canonicas.

Comment: Em resumo: Se a pergunta é razoavelmente aproveitável, razoavelmente original,  possui boas respostas e penso que há boas chances de outras pessoas terem o mesmo problema eu prefiro reabrir. Se a pergunta é razoavelmente aproveitável e se vejo várias pessoas tendo o mesmo problema de entendimento conceitual / julgo que existem boas chances de outras pessoas procurarem a mesma coisa no Google eu prefiro responder do que fechar. Não é raro que uma pergunta "borderline" que estou respondendo seja fechada. Geralmente eu só descubro que a pergunta já foi fechada depois que já postei a resposta :D.

Comment: Voltando ao tópico: É exatamente por isso que o combo: voto do OP + voto de quem respondeu + voto de usuário alheio para reabrir não me parece tão assustador. De fato gostaria de ver isso acontecendo mais frequentemente para salvar algum conteúdo bom do site. Entendo que sempre existe o risco de conteúdo ruim ser reaberto, mas realmente acredito que essa seja a exceção e não a regra quando o processo envolve 3 usuários de 3k+ reputação. Quando acontecer a solução é fechar a pergunta novamente como acontece no SOen.

Comment: Com a qualidade do conteúdo tão baixa como está, acho que é bem mais provável recuperar uma pergunta que um outro usuário respondeu e votou para reabrir do que perguntas fechadas editadas pelo próprio OP. É uma inversão de valores e uma realidade dura de encarar, mas esse é o momento do site. Talvez fosse o caso inclusive de exigir ainda mais reputação - ou mesmo exigir um bom histórico e um mínimo de ações de moderação - pelo privilégio de reabrir questões (pensando em mitigar o problema dos caçadores de reputação teimosos), mas gosto da ideia dos três votos.